# How to fix server in rescue mode after hardware failure?

Tags: centos, centos7

A couple of days ago I did a routine `yum update` on my CentOS 7 server, and then issued a `reboot` command.  The server never came back.  I contacted my webhost (OneProvider - they resell old Online.net boxes, I think), who FINALLY have fixed it, nearly 48 hours later.  They said it was a "dead fan" that needed to be replaced.

This is my last message from them:

`The fan of your server has been replaced.
It is reachable from the rescue mode.`

Ok, great.  But what steps do I need to take to get it up and running again?  I thought it might just be a case of rebooting into normal mode from my management console, but that didn't seem to work, so I've now switched back into rescue mode (FreeBSD_10.1_amd64), and logged in with the credentials supplied... but I have no idea what to do next?

Thank you

Comment: A dead fan wouldn't prevent booting.  The yum update may.  Have a look at the logs or try booting again and watch the console?

Comment: How do I get to the logs from rescue mode?  I think I need to mount the CentOS filesystem, but when I try `su` (I'm connected as my name, not as root) it just replies with `Sorry`, and when I try `mount`it says `Operation is not permitted`.  I'd like a bit of hand holding if you can! Thank you.

Comment: I must say a "rescue mode" where you are not root, is somewhat new to me.  If su fails, does sudo work?

Comment: I'm in an IPMI session on normal boot now, and it seems to be hanging on "Attempting Boot From Hard Drive (C:)" - which seems all sorts of weird to me as that sounds like a Windows error, not a Linux one...

Comment: Perhaps they gave you another system?  Does their control panel give you any information on what is installed?

Comment: I don't think that's the case... it says "CentOS 7.2, 64 bits" and still shows the same hostname I had set up before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106878/discussion-between-gerard-h-pille-and-codemonkey).

Comment: Apparently that message comes from the BIOS, which was written in a dos/windows style, and isn't indicative of the installed operating system.

Comment: Boot sector overwritten, not the same boot disk as before?

Comment: I'm in the chat Gerard.